# Пытаюсь установить Android Studio на rasberry pi 4. При запуске вылезает ошибка "Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted."

Tags: java, linux, android-studio, android-sdk, raspberry-pi

Скачал с офф сайта и распаковал архив в usr/local/. Потом запускаю ./studio.sh кликаю Далее/Стандартная установка/Далее/Выбираю тему/Далее/Вылезает An error occurred while trying to compute required packages./Далее/finish/вылезает Failed to determine required packages. Потом открывается окно AStudio. Кликаю новый проект. Вылезает Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted. Открываю SDK manager. Тыкаю Edit/Next/Next, но это не помогает. Что делать?

Comment: возможно, сдк, которое Вы установили не готово работать на arm процессоре, а только на x86/64. Что делать? искать подходящее сдк.

Comment: Я не ставил СДК. AStudio должно скачать его само, но оно не знает какие пакеты скачивать или что-то в этом роде.

Comment: я бы тоже на его месте не знал, что качать. Вот у людей такая же проблема  и они собирают все ручками https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54263814/building-android-sdk-tools-aapt-adb-etc-for-arm-arm64